# solving type errors produced by module type indirection

Tags: types, module, ocaml

The following code produces the type error `This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type ModuleA.t`, even though `ModuleA.t` and `float` are the same, as defined in `ModuleA`:

```
module type ModuleT =
  sig
    type t
    val to_string : t -> string
  end

module ModuleA : ModuleT =
  struct
    type t = float
    let to_string x = string_of_float x
  end

let () =
  let x = 3.0 in
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (ModuleA.to_string x)
```

If I don't define the module type `ModuleT`, but only `ModuleA`, the type error is gone. How can I solve the type error while keeping the module type definition?

Comment: In there an equivalent in another programming language of what you're aiming for? (Is it `interface ModuleT<t> {...} class ModuleA implements ModuleT<float> {...}`?)

Comment: yes, I basically want an interface like you described

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are hiding the definition of `t` in `ModuleT`, and the obvious solution given the lack of constraints in your question is to just define it fully:

```
module type ModuleT =
  sig
    type t = float
    val to_string : t -> string
  end
```

But depending on the reason for defining `ModuleT` in the first place, this solution might not be appropriate. For example, with `ModuleT` as you have defined it you could provide a `ModuleB` with the following definition:

```
module ModuleB : ModuleT =
  struct
    type t = int
    let to_string x = string_of_int x
    let make : int -> t = fun n -> n
  end

let () =
  let x = 3 in
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (ModuleB.to_string (ModuleB.make x))
```

If `t` in `ModuleT` is constrained as a `float` you can't do this, because `int` obviously won't unify with `float`.

Comment: The main motivation that led me to define the module type was to be able to restrict the modules I can pass as input to a module functor. But now I just realized that if I define a module functor that takes a `ModuleT` and I don't define a type for `ModuleA`, I can still pass it to the functor as long as it implements what says in `ModuleT`. So I guess my best option is to just define `ModuleA` without a type? Is this a common practice?

Comment: To clarify, my motivation for defining the module type was also to be able to define something like `ModuleB` in your example, but having in mind that I'd like to define a functor that could take either `ModuleA` or `ModuleB`, because both have `t` and `to_string`. With that in mind, would it be advisable to define `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` without a type and only specify the type in the module functor input?

Comment: As long as you have the type defined, and if  ´ModuleA´ and ´ModuleB´ would be submodules in any case, you might as well add the constraints as documentation. But I don't think it serves any other purpose. If they don't fit they'll fail when you try to use them anyway.